# Samsung smart tv unique device identifier

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to programmatically obtain some kind of unique device identifier from Samsung smart TV device.

The closest thing i found in documentation is `GetDUID` function on `SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-NNAVI` object, but it requires to provide mac address which confuses me as to what purpose of this function really is.

My question: how to obtain for example device serial number or other information that uniquely identifies it.

Comment: Wow. This on the one hand is a very good question, on the other hand, borders the too localized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accordingly to [SamsungDForum](http://www.samsungdforum.com) the way to get the [DUID](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=API00001&FileName=NNavi_183.html) ("Device Unique ID") is:

In index.html add:

```
<object id='pluginNetwork' border=0 classid='clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-NETWORK'></object>
<object id='pluginObjectNNavi' border=0 classid='clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-NNAVI'></object>
```

And somewhere in your Javascriptː

```
var networkPlugin = document.getElementById('pluginNetwork');
var nnaviPlugin = document.getElementById('pluginObjectNNavi');
var deviceId = nnaviPlugin.GetDUID(networkPlugin.GetHWaddr());
```

I know that you've seen this, but I honestly don't think that there's other solution.

edit: Please check [@IvanSolntsev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038781/samsung-smart-tv-unique-device-identifier/13910224?#13910224) answer if you're looking for a way to get the device ESN (Electronic Serial Number).

edit2: Updated DUID official documentation link.

Comment: I agree with @Rui. Don't know other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GetESN](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00011/deviceapi_externalwidgetinterface_getesn.html) function

in html:

```
<object id='pluginExternal' border=0 classid='clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-EXTERNALWIDGETINTERFACE'></object>
```

in javascript:

```
var ExternalWidgetInterface = document.getElementById('pluginExternal');
var sn = ExternalWidgetInterface.GetESN("NFLX");
```

Comment: Do you get the same result string using "GetESN" and "GetDUID" ?

Comment: No, GetESN is not exist in 2010 tv models API, it first appeared in 2011.
DUID is somehow depend of MAC address (You may get 2 different id's if tv use wired and wireless network). Returned values of GetESN and GetDUID always differs.