# PlayReady ClientID Individualization on Samsung SmartTVs

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, drm, playready

There is a fairly common practice to individualize the client of an app using the PlayReady IBX (Individualization Black Box). You can find more about this here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/playready4/archive/2011/10/10/ways-to-unqiuely-identify-a-silverlight-client.aspx but it is essentially a 'fake' license request to the license server that responds with the ClientID, then you can use this id to do whatever you may want.
It happens that I can't find any equivalent API for Samsung Smart TV system. I've read the PlayReady tutorial many times and the better candidate I've found was the SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-SEF object through the 'ProcessInitiatorsFromXml' call but I don't think it is going to work since I can't create the XML that contains the proper IBX ClientID.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use the DUID of the device to identify the client ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038781/samsung-smart-tv-unique-device-identifier/12113470)

Comment: Thank you Rui! But I need this id to authorise the playback before the license deliver, its a little unorthodox flow but it works for the other clients like web and smartphones so I can't change just for the TV :(

Comment: Ok, so why can't you make that call "manually" (like ajax...) ?

Comment: Samsung's PlayReady implementation (as implementation by any other vendor) should already have unique client Id per device - it is implemented as part of porting PlayReady to target platform. There is no individualization as all devices are already individualized.